# Is the Multiclass move meant to be single use?

Tags: dungeon-world

Is the multiclass move a one time use, or can you use the move repeatedly and swap out the skill that you take from another class?

Being a "Move", it would seem that you can use it whenever, but this seems a bit over-powered. Single use when you acquire the move seems more realistic.

I understand the GM can make a call here, but I want to best understand the rules as written.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a "one-time" use. You just take a move from another playbook, instead of a move you could normally take.

## [Citation needed]!

I'll try to base this interpretation with rules texts.

As we know, not every move has a Trigger. This is how many moves look like:

> When you **(do X; trigger)**, roll +Stat. On a 7-9, (Y happens). On a 10+, (Z happens).

But some moves look like this:

> (Y happens).

For example, the Armored move of many classes, or moves like this:

> **Still Hungry**
>   Choose an additional appetite.
>
> **Scent of Blood**
>   When you hack and slash an enemy, your next attack against that same foe deals +1d4 damage.

So the thing to learn here is that not every move is something that you can trigger. (You used the term, "use". In fact, you don't *use* moves, ever. You describe an action, and if it triggers a move you follow through that move.) Sometimes a move *is*.

So what does the Multiclass (Dabbler/Initiate/Master) move say?

> **Multiclass Dabbler** 
>   Get one move from another class. Treat your level as one lower for choosing the move.

Do what it says. You take one move from another class. It makes no mention about how or when you can change that one move. There is no trigger. You cannot trigger this move.

### Bottom line?

> Is the multiclass move a one time use, or **can you use the move** repeatedly and swap out the skill that you take from another class?

Is the key element here.

You cannot use a move.

You cannot use a Multiclass Dabbler move. You cannot trigger it, either, because there is no trigger.

### More support for this interpretation

Under Playing the Game, Character Change:

> Multiclass Moves
>
> The multiclass moves allow you to gain moves from another class. You get to choose any move of your level or lower. For the purpose of multiclassing, any starting class moves that depend on each other count as one move—the wizard’s cast a spell, spellbook, and prepare spells for example. If a move from another class refers to your level, count your levels from the level where you first gained a move from that class.

This gives the idea that you only get to choose *a* move, one move.

The example under Moves, Multiclass Moves:

> *When Ajax gains 3rd level he takes Multiclass Dabbler to get Commune and Cast a Spell from the Cleric class. He casts and prepares spells like a first level Cleric: first level spells and rotes only, a total of 2 levels of spells prepared. When he later gains 4th level, he prepares and casts spells as a second level Cleric.*

If Ajax could choose to take other moves as well, the example might be lengthier about how changing a move to another works when there are spells prepared, and how it affects Spells/Commune.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's one-time. You have to check it off when you pick it, and you can't check off an Advanced Move twice.

Being a *move* doesn't mean that you can keep “doing the move” to pick something different, either. A multiclass move has no trigger, so it never “happens”. The only time you can access it is when the sheet says so: “When you gain a level…” Otherwise you can't “do” a multiclass moves.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, you don't **use** moves in DW. The moves affect play per their description. There are three general flavors of moves that change how the game works for your character.

1. The most common type; **triggered moves**. These come into effect when you describe doing something that matches the trigger description. Hack and slash is the typical example.
2. More on the advanced side, the **modifier moves**. These enhance or alter how other moves (basic or class) work. Usually they give you more or better choices, or add a 12+ tier. They come into play through the move they modify.
3. The often underestimated **permission moves**. These allow you to access otherwise unavailable rules, moves or effects. Cast a spell is a typical example, and the multiclass moves are of this category, giving you permission to pick moves from other playbooks.

Now for the core of your question; since the *Multiclass dabbler/initiate/master* is a permission, it has no trigger. It does not manifest when you describe taking an action. It just allows you to do what it says in its text. And when you read it carefully, you will notice that it says

> **Get one move** from another class. …

*(Emphasis mine)*

It says "one move". Not more. It says "get". Not "access" or "use". It becomes one of your advanced moves like any other. That's it.

---

And there's another thing to be aware of in Dungeon World. *"Making a call"* or *"making house rules"* is not a part of the DM's principles, agenda or moves. Contrary to the tradition in many older RPG's including D&D, what the DM **can** do is pretty much prescribed and structured in DW. It is an integral part of how the game plays and those rules are **not** optional recommendations. The game does break if the DM fails to observe them. *Caveat dominus tenebrae!*

Comment: I appreciate the feedback